# Sending licensekey from client to server via WCF in header

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, endpoint

I want to authenticate app server against my central with license key and I do not want to include it as a parameter in my calls.

I have implemented custom ServiceAuthorizationManager but I am not sure what is the best way and place to set this licenseKey on client side.

I tried below (I might be completely wrong with approach)

```
<endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8000/ApiDataService"  binding="wsHttpBinding"
    contract="MyInterfaces.IApiDataService">
        <headers>
            <LicenseKey>MyLicenseKey</LicenseKey>
        </headers>
</endpoint>
```

then in ServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)

I have managed to find a header's index via:

```
operationContext.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.FindHeader("LicenseKey", "")
```

but retrieved HeaderInfo does not have my content any more.
I am sure it is in operationContext.RequestContext so I should be able to capture it somehow.

1. Any idead how?
2. Is there any nicer/standard way of doing this?
3. Should I use <identity\> element?

I am more than happy to use operationContext.ServiceSecurityContext but I do not know how to set it up on client side and where to place my custom license key.

I have multiple endpoints so I would prefer to have a single place for my license key. Setting it from code would be even better.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article here [Globalization Patterns in WCF (WS-I18N implementation)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WSI18N.aspx) may be of interest to you as it demonstrate how to use WCF out-of-band mechanisms to send and receive custom information. It's about globalization, not licensing of course, but the problem seems somewhat similar.

Comment: Thanks. it pointed me into right direction by implementing IDispatchMessageInspector and IClientMessageInspector.
My solution was a bit different. I have also implemented

    LicenseBehaviour: BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior, IServiceBehavior

as it is here: http://winterdom.com/2006/10/iservicebehavioridispatchmessageinspectorandendpoints